# Pulling an element out of a multidimensional array and changing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have a Multidimensional array:

```
listPatients =   [[  "Johnson",   "Fred", "N", "2763 Filibuster Drive",
 "Lakeland", "FL", "37643", "Q", "05/27/1935", "164-55-0726", "N"]] \
+                [[ "Williams",  "Betty", "L",    "701 Collage Avenue", 
"Orlando", "FL", "31234", "F", "11/27/1971", "948-44-1038", "Y"]] \
+                [[     "Ling", "Hector", "X",     "1500 Raceway Lane",
"Tampa", "FL", "32785", "M", "10/17/2003", "193-74-0274", "Y"]] \
+                [[    "Albin",   "Ross", "L",      "207 Daisy Avenue",
"Lakeland", "FL", "32643", "M", "12/08/1990", "458-57-2867", "N"]] \
+                [[ "Anderson",  "Jason", "O",       "1527 Lewis Road",
"Tampa", "FL", "32785", "M", "11/25/1991", "093-50-1093", "Y"]] \
+                [[     "Baca",  "Edwin", "L",       "25 Hunters Lane", 
"Lakeland", "FL", "32643", "M", "10/30/1992", "159-56-9731", "Y"]] \
+                [[   "Birner", "Dalton", "M",     "851 Applebe Court",
 "Orlando", "FL", "31234", "M", "09/22/1993", "695-21-2340", "Y"]] \
```

I want to use a for loop to extract the gender in element [7] and change it from "Q" to "M". I am currently using:

```
gender=["M","F"]
for patients in (listPatients):
    if patients[7]!= gender:
        print("Patient Gender Error")
        print(patients[0],patients[1],patients[2])
        patients[7]=input("Please Correct Gender Info:")
    else:
        ()
```

The output keeps repeating the entire array until its been through. I just want to correct the first list (patient) and be done.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the condition `if patients[7]!= gender` which tests a string vs a list, which will always be false. This is why the entire list is always printed.

Change this to the `not in` test instead:

```
if patients[7] not in gender:
```